# Why didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError returns an error == nil?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

In my AppDelegate.m file I register for remote notifications in APN(Apple Push Notifications), as usual.

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];`

and I have both callbacks methods implemented

`- (void) application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken {...}`

`- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error {...}`

At this time, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError is always called but the **error** associated is **nil**. So I can't find the reason of the failure.

Now here come the stranger things.

1. I have several targets based on the same code, and the rest of them
   are working properly with the push notifications of APN's. But one
   is not.
2. I'm 99,9% that the project configuration for the APN is right, because:

- The app has been working on production for several years, without any
  problem with APNs
- Other apps based on the same code are working properly with APNs.
- I have tested the app in old devices with **iOS12** and I'm able to
  registerForRemoteNotifications, and I'm receiving push
  notifications in TestFlight. The same version of TestFlight is not
  working with iSO14

The last point makes me think that maybe the problem comes with iOS14 but I'm not able to find why, as the other targets are registering without any problem in APN on iOS14 devices.

This app is based in Objective-C mixed with Swift. Xcode Version 12.2 (12B45b).

- Tested on iPhone SE (1st) and iPhone 11 both with iOS 14.2. (Not able
  to register in APN)
- Tested on iPhone 6 and iPhone 11 both with iOS 12.4.9 (Able to register with exactly the same code)